# What are the definitions for `isoToEquiv` and `iso`?

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

This is from the [2019 Cubical Agda intro paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela//icfp19.pdf).

They are not in `Cubical.Core.Everything` and even file content search for the Cubical v0.1 library is not turning up anything for me.

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Data.Nat

data Pos : Set where
  pos1 : Pos
  x0 : Pos → Pos
  x1 : Pos → Pos

data Bin : Set where
  bin0 : Bin
  binPos : Pos → Bin

ℕ≃Bin : ℕ ≃ Bin
ℕ≃Bin = isoToEquiv (iso ℕ→Bin Bin→ℕ Bin→ℕ→Bin ℕ→Bin→ℕ)
```

I am trying to get this short fragment near the start to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find those in `Cubical.Foundations.Isomorphism` and `Cubical.Foundations.Equiv`